# Gatsby: Fetching json file after initial page load

Tags: reactjs, performance, asynchronous, gatsby

I'm building my first PWA with Gatsby. I have a 3mb json file with an array of objects. The function of this app is that you can search the json file for two objects (by either their name or a matching alias) and retrieve all data about both objects.
This app is only running on a single URL endpoint and when loading I am downloading the entire json file immediately by querying all fields with

```
export const example = graphql`
  allDataJson{
    ...examplesubCategories
  }`
```

and accessing the data through the data-prop passed to the component through this query.

```
const fullInfo = data.allDataJson.edges[0].node.example
```

I felt that fetching the data in useEffect once the home page had mounted would make the most sense, and I could display a loading spinner while that happened.

My two questions are

1: Is there a way to fetch this data from the component when deployed as it is not in a database and instead stored in src/data/example.json? (If not is there an alternative to remove the json file from the initial page fetch)

2: Currently once the bundle has downloaded the entire app is available offline as a PWA, If there was a way to achieve Q1 would this data automatically be saved with gatsby's default offline-plugin settings or would I have to manually cache this data to make the app available offline.

A live version of this is available at https://tripmix.netlify.app/ if it helps to see.

Answer (score 1):

Move the file to `static/data/example.json`. On build, Gatsby will copy the contents of the `static` folder to `public`, making this file available at `/static/data/example.json`. Then you can just issue a `fetch` to that URL to fetch the data client-side.

You shouldn't have any issues adding this URL to the `precachePages` option in the `gatsby-plugin-offline` configuration ([docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-offline/)), though if you set up your HTTP headers to cache this file for a long duration it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much Corey, This was a great help!